# Excel VBA - Multiple selections for drop-down list on several columns

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using VBA code to enable selecting several options on a drop-down list, but I can only make it work on one column.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'Code by Sumit Bansal from https://trumpexcel.com
' To allow multiple selections in a Drop Down List in Excel (without repetition)
Dim Oldvalue As String
Dim Newvalue As String
Application.EnableEvents = True
On Error GoTo Exitsub
If Target.Column = 8 Then
  If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
    GoTo Exitsub
  Else: If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub Else
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Newvalue = Target.Value
    Application.Undo
    Oldvalue = Target.Value
      If Oldvalue = "" Then
        Target.Value = Newvalue
      Else
        If InStr(1, Oldvalue, Newvalue) = 0 Then
            Target.Value = Oldvalue & ", " & Newvalue
      Else:
        Target.Value = Oldvalue
      End If
    End If
  End If
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exitsub:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Does anyone know how to include several columns, rather than just a single one?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Change `If.Target.Column = 8` to include the other columns?

Comment: Btw, you can remove the first instance of `Application.EnableEvents = True` and also the second to last instance.

Answer (score 0):

First this have to be a public Sub for use in any sheet. Put it in a module (not in the sheet code)
Take two paramaters plus an optional:  1) the "target" cell  2) a  STRING with: a)the target columns comma separated or b) the Target.Validation.Formula1 (whitch begins with "=") OR a range with the desired cells 3) Optional separator string = ", ".
Α correction was made to the repeated input check so that if there is value e.g.: "seagull", then to be able to choose "sea". Using as second parameter the Validation.Formula1 e.g: "=ANY_RANGE" is very usefull, because you define the cells without caring about their position within the sheet.

```vb
    '---------use the sub below from within any sheet like this:---------
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
       Call multiSelection(Target, Me.Range("D15:E17"))  'work with ceels in a range
       Call multiSelection(Target, "8,10,12,15")         'work with ceels in columns list
       Call multiSelection(Target, "=A_NAMED_RANGE")         'work with ceels whitch have the Target.Validation.Formula1 equal to "=A_NAMED_RANGE"
    End Sub

    Public Sub multiSelection(ByVal Target As Range, allTargets As Variant, Optional sep as String = ", ")
       Dim Oldvalue As String, Newvalue As String, whatIs As String
       On Error GoTo Exitsub
       
       With Target
          If .Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Set Target = Target.Cells(1, 1)
          If .value = "" Or Not hasListValidation(Target) Then Exit Sub
          whatIs = TypeName(allTargets)
          If whatIs = "Range" Then
             If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
             If Intersect(Target, allTargets) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
          ElseIf whatIs = "String" Then
             If Left(Trim(allTargets), 1) = "=" Then
                If Target.Validation.Formula1 <> allTargets Then Exit Sub
             Else
                allTargets = Replace(Replace(allTargets, " ", ""), ",", separ)
                If InStr(1, separ & allTargets & separ, separ & .Column & separ) <= 0 Then Exit Sub
             End If
          Else
             MsgBox ("Sub multiSelection, parameter: allTargets, must be Range or String")
             Exit Sub
          End If
          Application.EnableEvents = False
          Newvalue = .Value:      Application.Undo:    Oldvalue = .Value
          If Oldvalue = "" Then
             .Value = Newvalue
          Else
             If InStr(1, sep & Oldvalue & sep, sep & Newvalue & sep) = 0 Then
                .Value = Oldvalue & sep & Newvalue
             Else
                .Value = Oldvalue
             End If
          End If
       End With
    Exitsub:
       Application.EnableEvents = True
       On Error GoTo 0
    End Sub

    Public Function hasListValidation(r As Range) As Boolean
       Dim t: t = Null
       On Error Resume Next
       t = r.Validation.Type
       On Error GoTo 0
       If Not IsNull(t) Then
          hasListValidation = (t = xlValidateList)
       End If
    End Function
```