# How do I get drop-downs with non-selectable sub-headings and empty rows ignored in Excel 2019?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, ms-office, spreadsheet

I have the area for the list items in the drop-downs on another worksheet, in adjacent cells from top to bottom except for some rows (so there are blank lines between some list items). Some more rows in this range might sometimes be empty though, so I need Excel to ignore these rows when displaying the list items in the drop-downs on Sheet B.

In the source range on Sheet A, there will be sub-headings (e.g. "Fruits", "Vegetables" etc.) that also should be displayed on Sheet B in the drop-downs (but it should not be possible to select any of the sub-heading themselves).

And the range might become a few rows bigger or smaller.

How do I best go about to accomplish above? Is VBA needed?

The drop-downs should be on Sheet B, in a sample Excel that I would like to upload here in the range A4:G10.

And the source range of the drop-down list items are on Sheet A, in the sample Excel that I would like to upload here in the range A8:A20 (the sub-headings in that range are "Vegetable" and "Fruit", cells A8 and A13; it should not be possible to select these - they should only be displayed in the drop-downs).

The problem is with the blank rows and that the sub-headings should be displayed in the drop-downs but not selectable. So I hope to get the sub-headings displayed on Sheet B in the dropdowns (non-selectable sub-headings) and have a dynamic range on Sheet A (the source for the drop-downs), a range which is now A8:A20 but might be longer or smaller. I hope also to find a solution which accommodates for the possibility that some cells sometimes are empty in the source on Sheet A (like now, where cells A13, A14, A19, A20 are empty in the range A8:A20).

Comment: Vba would be advisable. It could be accomplished with creating a named range referring to a formula with INDEX and AGGREGATE, but this will most likely slow your file down a lot. In newer Excel you could use FILTER and refer to the spill range

Comment: " in a sample Excel that I would like to upload here," You said, and where is it? I should be able to do this with VBA. However, actual example files and demos (videos or screenshots ) must be available to illustrate the requirements.

Comment: I don't believe it is possible to show a value in the dropdown list but not allow it to be selected, not even with VBA. You could do a VBA `Worksheet_Change` macro to watch if the user selects a sub-heading, then throw a message, and change their selection to something else, but even that would only run after they click a sub-heading. Or, a simpler solution might be to use conditional formatting or a cell to indicate to the user they have made an invalid selection.

Comment: Please read the guidance on how to aka question on SO.

Comment: When I posted the question I couldn't find any icon for uploading my sample Excel file.

Anyway, as to ignoring blank rows, wouldn't the part "How to create a dynamic dropdown list in Excel" work for my case?:

https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/excel-drop-down-list/

("so it returns a reference to a range that includes only non-empty cells")

Comment: And for non-selectable sub-headings in each drop-down list, what about a solution where the user picks a sub heading but when he picks it an error message pops up saying it can't be selected (the cell value will remain the same)?

Comment: If it is convenient for you, give me an Excel sample to try (leave a download or share link), otherwise, do I have to create my own relevant data to test? THANKS

Comment: Here is my sample Excel:

https://files.fm/u/47m76d9de

But "Orange" and "Banana" are missing in the drop-downs on Sheet B. I have added a named formula using Ctrl+F3 with a formula consisting of OFFSET and COUNTA, but the COUNTA seems to not work when there are blanks both within the range and in the end of the range.

Comment: What can certainly be done is the following: Display all the fields in the list, but if one that will have as the first character, for example the star * or anything else is defined, even though the user will click on it, the cell will not be entered and the list will close. This can be done with a variation of my answer to another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76143074/15794828

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's All done. Please [download it](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tDIlGupA7_e7B9cpmOqL7zTbtw_xl0hw/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=106108182093734588005&rtpof=true&sd=true)  to check it out.

The [sample file](https://files.fm/u/47m76d9de), Sheet A cell **O4** still has formula data in it, and

> … (the sub-headings in that range are "Vegetable" and "Fruit", cells A8 and A13 …

in this file is A15, not A13. I've ignored both of them.

#### Remark:

The two name range **might be longer or smaller**, as long as you are adding and removing cells from these two name ranges, and not from their boundaries. Or you can modify it from the following two constant values in the program code.

```vb
Public Const DropDownsSourceRangeDefaultAddress As String = "$A$8:$A$20"
Public Const DropDownsRangeAddress As String = "$A$4:$G$10"

'this one will get the changed range by user
Public DropDownsSourceRangeAddress As String
```

You should download [it](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tDIlGupA7_e7B9cpmOqL7zTbtw_xl0hw/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=106108182093734588005&rtpof=true&sd=true) to test it to make sure it is the effect you want. After downloading, remember to **enable the macro.** If you can get an *error message* when some sub-heading is selected in a drop-down,
[image: you can get an error message when some sub-heading is selected in a drop-down]
it means that the file's program is working properly on your end, just like it is on my end.
Or you will see some like:
[image: Enable the Edit file]
[image: Enable the macro]
*(I only have the traditional Chinese version!)*
then you have to enable the macro just click the button in the green circle in the image above.
Or put the file in the Trusted directory to run macros before opening it, please reference these articles

[Enable or disable macros in Microsoft 365 files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/enable-or-disable-macros-in-microsoft-365-files-12b036fd-d140-4e74-b45e-16fed1a7e5c6)

[Run a macro](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/run-a-macro-5e855fd2-02d1-45f5-90a3-50e645fe3155)

[Change macro security settings in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-macro-security-settings-in-excel-a97c09d2-c082-46b8-b19f-e8621e8fe373)

Otherwise, the program will not run or run in error. If you are still unsure, you will have to copy the codes I posted below and add them to the correct location in the Excel .xlsm or .xlsb file for the program to run properly. (Modules in the general module *(模組)* and objects in the class module *(物件)* and name them like) :

[image]
*press Alt + F11 to open this [VBE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/glossary/vbe-glossary)*

[Demo: Add code to your file.](https://youtube.com/live/X8Gb6N_1s70?feature=share) *(How to move these four pieces of VBA code below to your real, big Excel workbook.)* [**see also**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76282094/8249058)

## code

### Module "DropDownOP"

*(Original Name is "Module1")*

```vb
Option Explicit
Rem Each of the following conditions is subject to your discretion. For now, it looks like the conditions you invented in  Stackoverflow
Rem Each condition can be specified by the following constants (i.e. the value in double quotes), without having to enter the code to make changes
'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76268864/how-do-i-get-drop-downs-with-non-selectable-sub-headings-and-empty-rows-ignored
Public Const DropDownsSourceRangeName As String = "Food_items"
Public Const DropDownsRangeName As String = "DropDownsRange"
Public Const DropDownsSourceSheetName As String = "Sheet A"
Public Const DropDownsSheetName As String = "Sheet B"
Public Const DropDownsSourceRangeDefaultAddress As String = "$A$8:$A$20"
Public Const DropDownsRangeAddress As String = "$A$4:$G$10"

'this one will get the changed range by user
Public DropDownsSourceRangeAddress As String


Sub AddNamedRange()
    'DeleteNamedRanges
    DropDownsSourceRangeAddress = CheckDropDownsSourceNamedRange
    If DropDownsSourceRangeAddress <> "" Then
        ThisWorkbook.Names(DropDownsSourceRangeName).RefersTo = "='" + DropDownsSourceSheetName + "'!" + DropDownsSourceRangeAddress
    Else
        ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=DropDownsSourceRangeName, RefersTo:="='" + DropDownsSourceSheetName + "'!" + DropDownsSourceRangeDefaultAddress
    End If
    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=DropDownsRangeName, RefersTo:="='" + DropDownsSheetName + "'!" + DropDownsRangeAddress
End Sub

Function CheckDropDownsSourceNamedRange() As String
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Dim n As Name
    For Each n In ThisWorkbook.Names
        If n.Name = DropDownsSourceRangeName Then
            CheckDropDownsSourceNamedRange = n.RefersToRange.Address
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next n
    
    Exit Function
    
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "An error occurred: " & Err.Description
End Function

Sub DeleteNamedRanges()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Dim i As Long
    For i = ThisWorkbook.Names.Count To 1 Step -1
        Select Case ThisWorkbook.Names(i).Name
            Case DropDownsSourceRangeName, DropDownsRangeName
                ThisWorkbook.Names(i).Delete
            Case Else
                If InStr(ThisWorkbook.Names(i).Name, DropDownsSourceRangeName) Or _
                    InStr(ThisWorkbook.Names(i).Name, DropDownsRangeName) Then _
                        ThisWorkbook.Names(i).Delete
        End Select
    Next i
    
    Exit Sub
    
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "An error occurred: " & Err.Description
End Sub

Sub SetDropDownList()
   
   'set drop-downs
   Dim cell As Range, strFormula1 As String
   strFormula1 = getFormula1
   For Each cell In Sheets(DropDownsSheetName).Range(DropDownsRangeName).Cells
     
     'clear cells' value ,If needed
     'cell.Clear
     
      With cell.Validation
          .Delete 'clear existd Validation rules
          .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                        Operator:=xlBetween, _
                        Formula1:=strFormula1
          .IgnoreBlank = True
          .InCellDropdown = True
          .InputTitle = "Select a value"
          .ErrorTitle = "Invalid Value"
          .InputMessage = "Please select a value from the list."
          .ErrorMessage = "Please select a valid value from the list."
          .ShowInput = True
          .ShowError = True
       End With
    Next cell
End Sub
Function getFormula1() As String
    Dim f As String, arr, e
    arr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Range(DropDownsSourceRangeName))
    For Each e In arr
        If Not VBA.IsEmpty(e) Then
            f = f & e & ","
        End If
    Next
    f = Left(f, Len(f) - 1)
    getFormula1 = f
End Function
```

### Module "SheetsOP"

```vb
Option Explicit

'https://stackoverflow.com/a/76238510/8249058
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target = "" Then Exit Sub
    Dim c As Range
    Set c = ActiveCell
    Dim Cancel As Boolean
    Cancel = BeforeCellChange(Target)
    If Cancel Then
        MsgBox "You can't select this one: '" + Target.Value + "'" + vbCr + vbCr + vbTab + "Try again. ", vbCritical
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target.Value = ""
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        c.Offset(Target.Row - c.Row, Target.Column - c.Column).Select
    End If
End Sub
Function BeforeCellChange(ByVal Target As Range) As Boolean
    Rem set your rule
    Dim dictSubHeadings As Object, cell As Range
    Set dictSubHeadings = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For Each cell In ThisWorkbook.Sheets(DropDownOP.DropDownsSourceSheetName).Range(DropDownOP.DropDownsSourceRangeName)
        'if it is sub-headings
        If cell.Font.Underline And cell.Font.Bold And VBA.Left(cell.Value, 1) = "*" And VBA.Right(cell.Value, 1) = "*" Then 
            dictSubHeadings(cell.Value) = cell.Value
        End If
    Next cell
    If dictSubHeadings.exists(Target.Value) Then BeforeCellChange = True
    dictSubHeadings.RemoveAll
    Set dictSubHeadings = Nothing
End Function
```

### object Sheet2 "Sheet B"

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    'automatically update the dropdown list values when switching to Sheet B
    DropDownOP.SetDropDownList
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    SheetsOP.Worksheet_Change Target
End Sub
```

### object "ThisWorkbook"

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    AddNamedRange
End Sub
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253733/discussion-on-answer-by-oscar-sun-how-do-i-get-drop-downs-with-non-selectable-s); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.