# How do I move four pieces of Excel VBA code snippets from the sample Excel to my real, big Excel workbook?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, ms-office, spreadsheet

I accepted Oscar Sun's answer in this question on Stack Overflow:

[How do I get drop-downs with non-selectable sub-headings and empty rows ignored in Excel 2019?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76268864/how-do-i-get-drop-downs-with-non-selectable-sub-headings-and-empty-rows-ignored?noredirect=1#comment134497265_76268864)

The final sample Excel workbook is this one:

[File Dynamic-Data-Validation (from SO 20230517).xlsb](https://files.fm/u/bfnzpy39q)

There are four pieces of Excel VBA code that I need to move from above sample Excel to a big Excel workbook where there is lots of other VBA code (10 module codes and lots of sheet codes).

Of these four code snippets in the sample Excel, I've moved two already: "Module1" (I renamed it to "Module6" in my big Excel) and "object Sheet2 Sheet B" (I renamed "Sheet B" to my own sheet name in my big Excel). I made some changes in "Module1" ("Module6") also in my big Excel.

But I don't understand how and where to move these codes from the sample Excel:

"Module SheetsOP"
"object ThisWorkbook" (renamed in the latest updated sample Excel to "DropDownOP")

"Module SheetsOP", do I just move it to a module VBA code page that I give the name "Module SheetsOP"?

For "object ThisWorkbook", in my big Excel I already have below VBA code snippet udner "ThisWorkbook":

```
Sub copypasterange()

Set Src = Application.InputBox("Select a source cell", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)
Set Dst = Application.InputBox("Select a destination cell", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)

Src.Copy
Dst.PasteSpecial (xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme)
Dst.PasteSpecial (xlPasteColumnWidths)
Dst.PasteSpecial (xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme)

Count = 0
For Each Row In Src.Rows
    Dst.Offset(rowoffset:=Count).RowHeight = Row.RowHeight
    Count = Count + 1
Next
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

End Sub
```

Should I just add the VBA code from the sample workbook from "object ThisWorkbook" to after "End Sub" in my current "ThisWorkbook" VBA code?

I have tried moving two of the four Excel VBA code snippets from the sample Excel workbook to my real, big Excel workbook. I still can't see any drop-downs displayed. So I need to move the remaining two Excel VBA code snippets also.

I understand now, the two remaining VBA code snippets to move are both module codes: "object ThisWorkbook" (renamed to "SheetsOP" by Oscar in his latest sample Excel) and "DropDownOP".

My current modules in the VBA editor in my real, big Excel are these (they are displayed in this order):

Module1
Module10
Module16
Module19
Module2
Module21
Module3
Module4
Module5
Module6 (this is the "Module1" from the sample Excel, but as I already have a "Module1" in my big Excel I had to rename it to "Module6").

Can I just give any module name to the two remaining modules I need to move, such as "Module7" for "DropDownOP" and "Module8" for "Module SheetsOP"?

Answer (score 1):

### Demo

Please refer to the video of [my demonstration](https://www.youtube.com/live/X8Gb6N_1s70?feature=share), [demo again](https://youtube.com/live/YRfMRQm1NKo?feature=share)

### Step-by-Step

- 

> Can I just give any module name to the two remaining modules I need to move, such as "Module7" for "DropDownOP" and "Module8" for "Module SheetsOP"?

No, you have to keep the original name, as it may be referenced in the code. If you change the name, there will be an error of not finding the reference name.

- Now the name of "Module1" is "DropDownOP" already, so please remove your "Module6". OK? Just apply my most new code to run: Add the "DropDownOP" in this .xlsb file to Modules in your project, which should be placed in a group with the other modules *(…Module1 Module10 Module16 Module19 Module2 Module21 Module3 Module4 Module5…)* in the project pane *(top-left pane of the VBE)*.
- And add the "**SheetsOP**" Module, too.

> The easiest way to do these two steps is by **dragging and dropping**, either *between the File Explorer and the Project Pane* or *between projects* in the Project Pane. Please refer to the video above.

- And the object "**ThisWorkbook**", In the case you show,

```vb
Sub copypasterange()

Set ……

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

End Sub
```

since you already have it,

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

End Sub
```

so, just put

```vb
    AddNamedRange
```

in the middle of the *sub* and *end sub* blocks.

- The final object code is the Sheet2 named "**Sheet B**", You have to find your Sheet B in the *project pane*, double click on it to open its code viewing pane *(the right and biggest one of the VBE)*, then look for the procedure *(sub)* names **Worksheet_Activate** and **Worksheet_Change**,*(you can press Ctrl + f to Find)* if these two exist, then do the same as the previous **Workbook_Open**, if they don't exist, then copy the code between the *Sub* and *end sub* (containing these two lines) to the code area in the code viewing pane of the Sheet B you just clicked twice to open.  Just paste them in the blank space between any *end sub* and *sub*(or *private sub*).
- The final result should look like this：
  [image: The final result 1]
  [image: The final result 2]

### Ready to go

- when above all are set, click **debug -> compile** on the menu:
  [image]
- If there is no error message box shown then you can save the file and happily test it yep.

For more information, please refer to my previous demo video. Thank you.

- If you still do not exactly sure what and how to do, then we may meet via [Google Meet](https://meet.google.com/vaa-tyhh-xug) and use [Chrome Remote Desktop](https://remotedesktop.google.com/?pli=1) or [TeamViewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en-us/)  to share your screen with me, I'll hands-on instruct you.

Comment: @Sun, for Sheet B, I get this error message under Debug/Compile VBA project:

Compile error:
Ambigious name detected: Worksheet_Change

My Code:

Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    SheetsOP.Worksheet_Change Target
    Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    'automatically update the dropdown list values when switching to Sheet B
    DropDownOP.SetDropDownList
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    SheetsOP.Worksheet_Change Target
End Sub
End Sub

Comment: @Unicorn Just keep a **Change** event procedure. Combine the code in the two Change events. Remember not to have duplicate.

Comment: You can give me Google meet or Skype or teamviewer screen sharing, or I can watch your screen and guide you, or I can help you with it. OK? @Unicorn

Comment: Do you mean that I should only keep the first part of the VBA?: Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    SheetsOP.Worksheet_Change Target
    Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    'automatically update the dropdown list values when switching to Startlistor från ATG.se
    DropDownOP.SetDropDownList
End Sub

Comment: I deleted the last part, but upon debugging I get this error message for ThisWorkbook: Compile error: Ambiguous name detected: AddNamedRange The row Private Sub Workbook_Open () is marked in yellow colour. The row AddNamedRange is marked in blue colour.

Comment: *Compile error: Ambiguous name detected:* means you had duplicate procedure name in the same module. That cause the code can not be identified by the compiler. @Unicorn

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253993/discussion-between-oscar-sun-and-unicorn).