# In my Excel VBA, how can I add more defined variables for adding two more source sheets with ranges for drop-downs?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office, spreadsheet

This is my DropDownOP VBA:

```
Option Explicit

Public Const DropDownsSourceRangeName As String = "Angle"
Public Const DropDownsRangeName As String = "DropDownsRange"
Public Const DropDownsSourceSheetName As String = "Angles for estimation"
Public Const DropDownsSheetName As String = "Fundfakt-kateg-vinkl"
Public Const DropDownsSourceRangeAddress As String = "$A$8:$A$1008"
Public Const DropDownsRangeAddress As String = "$AC$4:$AI$18"

Sub AddNamedRange()
    DeleteNamedRanges
    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=DropDownsSourceRangeName, RefersTo:="='" + DropDownsSourceSheetName + "'!" + DropDownsSourceRangeAddress
    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=DropDownsRangeName, RefersTo:="='" + DropDownsSheetName + "'!" + DropDownsRangeAddress
End Sub

Sub DeleteNamedRanges()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Dim i As Long
    For i = ThisWorkbook.Names.Count To 1 Step -1
        Select Case ThisWorkbook.Names(i).Name
            Case DropDownsSourceRangeName, DropDownsRangeName
                ThisWorkbook.Names(i).Delete
            Case Else
                If InStr(ThisWorkbook.Names(i).Name, DropDownsSourceRangeName) Or _
                    InStr(ThisWorkbook.Names(i).Name, DropDownsRangeName) Then _
                        ThisWorkbook.Names(i).Delete
        End Select
    Next i
    
    Exit Sub
    
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "An error occurred " & Err.Description
End Sub

Sub SetDropDownList()
   
   'set drop-downs
   Dim cell As Range
   For Each cell In Sheets(DropDownsSheetName).Range(DropDownsRangeName).Cells
     
     'clear cells' value ,If needed
     'cell.Clear
     
      With cell.Validation
          .Delete 'clear existd Validation rules
          .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                        Operator:=xlBetween, _
                        Formula1:=getFormula1
          .IgnoreBlank = True
          .InCellDropdown = True
          .InputTitle = vbNullString '"Select a value"
          .ErrorTitle = "Invalid value"
          .InputMessage = "Angle"
          .ErrorMessage = "Select a valid value in the list."
          .ShowInput = True
          .ShowError = True
       End With
    Next cell
End Sub
Function getFormula1() As String
    Dim f As String, arr, e
    arr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Range(DropDownsSourceRangeName))
    For Each e In arr
        If Not VBA.IsEmpty(e) Then
            f = f + e + ","
        End If
    Next
    f = Left(f, Len(f) - 1)
    getFormula1 = f
End Function
```

And this is the SheetsOP VBA:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target = "" Then Exit Sub
    Dim c As Range
    Set c = ActiveCell
    Dim Cancel As Boolean
    Cancel = BeforeCellChange(Target)
    If Cancel Then
        MsgBox "You can't select a heading: '" + Target.Value + "'" + vbCr + vbCr + vbTab + "Try again. ", vbCritical
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target.Value = ""
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        c.Offset(Target.Row - c.Row, Target.Column - c.Column).Select
    End If
End Sub
Function BeforeCellChange(ByVal Target As Range) As Boolean
    Rem set your rule
    Dim dictSubHeadings As Object, cell As Range
    Set dictSubHeadings = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For Each cell In ThisWorkbook.Sheets(DropDownOP.DropDownsSourceSheetName).Range(DropDownOP.DropDownsSourceRangeName)
        'if it is sub-headings
        If cell.Font.Underline And cell.Font.Bold And VBA.Left(cell.Value, 1) = "*" And VBA.Right(cell.Value, 1) = "*" Then
            dictSubHeadings(cell.Value) = cell.Value
        End If
    Next cell
    If dictSubHeadings.exists(Target.Value) Then BeforeCellChange = True
    dictSubHeadings.RemoveAll
    Set dictSubHeadings = Nothing
End Function
```

With these two VBAs as they are now, I have drop-downs on the sheet Fundfakt-kateg-vinkl in the range AC4:AI18 as you can see in the uploaded sample Excel. The source list items for these drop-downs are on the sheet Angles for estimation, in the range A8:A1008 (most rows are empty on list items). There are two named ranges now - Angle and DropDownsRange

I need to add two more source sheets in the VBA to retrieve list items to the last sheet, Fundfakt-kateg-vinkl, to the ranges Q4:W18 (from source sheet Categories for estimation) and A4:K18 (from source sheet Fundamentals for estimation). How can I do that by adding more definitions of the variables in the beginning of the VBA DropDownOP and what more needs to be done?

Relevent for this posting, here is my previous question regarding how to create the DropDownOP and the SheetsOP:

[How do I get drop-downs with non-selectable sub-headings and empty rows ignored in Excel 2019?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76268864/how-do-i-get-drop-downs-with-non-selectable-sub-headings-and-empty-rows-ignored/76274301#76274301)

I have uploaded a sample Excel here: https://easyupload.io/tmj3in

One last thing that I couldn't get to work in this sample Excel is truncating the list items from source sheet Angles for estimation in the source range address A8:A1008. In my original Excel, all list items are displayed without any blank row between them and without all empty rows from A22:A1008.

Finally, the existing VBA in for my sheet where the SheetsOP should be inserted have to be combined with the SheetsOP. This is the existing VBA for the sheet:

```
    Option Explicit
    
    Private Sub Worksheet_Activate() 'here is wrong!! there is a Sub but without End Sub ,so the error msg shown
        'automatically update the dropdown list values when switching to YYY from XXX.com
        DropDownOP.SetDropDownList
    End Sub
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        SheetsOP.Worksheet_Change Target
    End Sub
```

An update Thursday 7th September of the sample workbook where I have added a fifth sheet - Overview, which you can download from here:

https://easyupload.io/8jza2b

The drop-downs on sheet Overview are in the three grey-shaded cell ranges, columns G, H, I, AV. The current VBA (in the sample Excel) for this sheet Overview is the problem, I don't know how to change it so that I don't get any error when selecting a list item. The list items in all drop-downs on sheet Overview are not retrieved from any source sheet but have been entered in data validation lists.

Comment: "And so on" does not have much of a meaning... If you would do everything correct, it should work. Please, edit your code and show what lines did you add in existing Subs.

Comment: Do you really need help? If you do not even try putting yourself in our shoes it would be very difficult to be helped. Do you want us guessing what you did wrong when tried adapting the code? Then, do you want us building the necessary environment (a workbook with the necessary sheets) and offer you a (tested) solution? Can you, at least. sharing the workbook you tried adapting? Anyhow, the actual code can be improved from some points of view, besides the problem you try (only) describing... For instance, aren't the headers to be excepted as the first element in the list?

Comment: If you share the workbook you need to use in a reasonable period of time I will try helping, even if your question does not meet the regular requirements. Otherwise, the answer to your question would be: **No, only "adding definitions" it is  obviously not enough**... These new sheets, ranges, names etc. must be processed in a similar way. Maybe, with some improvements.

Comment: How can I share my sample Excel file here? I know it's not possible to upload a file as attachment to a question. Is there any other way I can share my Excel file?

Comment: Only in the same way you did when placed your first question. The staying period of the file is limited, anyhow...

Comment: As the staying period of the file (link to download site, as there is no option for file upload when I edit my question) is limited, if you can let me know when you are available and I will post the download link for you here at a suitable hour of your day.

Comment: This shouldn't be an issue. Any such (free) transfer site keeps the file on their cloud between 7 and 30 days, according to your choice, from this point of view. [This one](https://easyupload.io/) is free and easy to be used.

Comment: Thanks for the file repository link. I have uploaded my sample file there now: 
https://easyupload.io/tmj3in     I did some edits of my original question also.

Comment: Downloaded the file and looked to your updated question. As I said above, **If you do not even try putting yourself in our shoes it would be very difficult to be helped**, how do you imagine that I can do anything **if you deleted the new variables defining the necessary range addresses, sheet names, range names**? What do you expect from me? I don't event remember how many such ranges, names etc. you had...

Comment: I have entered sheet name where the drop-downs are and high-lighted the three ranges on this sheet where drop-downs are. I have entered the range for each of total 3 source sheet names that drop-downs are retrieved from. I have high-lighed all ranges in my sample. And the VBA that needs to be changed is in my sample.

Comment: This is not a way of **helping** us understanding... To search through the sheets to find the highlighted ranges in order to use their addresses? Was it so difficult to write their address? I am starting to loose my enthusiasm... **I will try doing it in your way**, but this is definitely not an appropriate way to ask for help.

Answer (score 1):

Please, use the next solution:

1. Copy the code in a **standard module**:

```
 Option Explicit

Public Const DropDownsSourceRangeName As String = "Angle"
Public Const DropDownsRangeName As String = "DropDownsRange"
Public Const DropDownsSourceSheetName As String = "Angles for estimation"
Public Const DropDownsSheetName As String = "Fundfakt-kateg-vinkl"
Public Const DropDownsSourceRangeAddress As String = "$A$8:$A$1008"
Public Const DropDownsRangeAddress As String = "$AC$4:$AI$18"

'declarations for the new part:
Public Const DropDownsSourceSheetName2 As String = "Categories for estimation"
Public Const DropDownsSourceSheetName3 As String = "Fundamentals for estimation"

Public Const DropDownsRangeName2 As String = "DropDownsRange1"
Public Const DropDownsRangeName3 As String = "DropDownsRange2"

Public Const DropDownsSourceRangeName2 As String = "Angle1"
Public Const DropDownsSourceRangeName3 As String = "Angle2"

Public Const DropDownsSourceRange2Address As String = "$A$8:$A$1008"
Public Const DropDownsSourceRange3Address As String = "$A$8:$A$22" 'source for Fundamentals...

Public Const DropDownsRange2Address As String = "$Q$4:$W$18"
Public Const DropDownsRange3Address As String = "$A$4:$G$18"

Sub AddNamedRangeAndSetDropDown()
    DeleteNamedRanges
    
    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=DropDownsSourceRangeName, RefersTo:="='" & DropDownsSourceSheetName & "'!" & DropDownsSourceRangeAddress 'Angle for estimation
    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=DropDownsRangeName, RefersTo:="='" & DropDownsSheetName & "'!" & DropDownsRangeAddress 'where to place the DropDown based on above source
    
    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=DropDownsSourceRangeName2, RefersTo:="='" & DropDownsSourceSheetName2 & "'!" & DropDownsSourceRange2Address 'Categories for estimation
    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=DropDownsRangeName2, RefersTo:="='" & DropDownsSheetName & "'!" & DropDownsRange2Address 'where to place the DropDown based on above source
    
    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=DropDownsSourceRangeName3, RefersTo:="='" & DropDownsSourceSheetName3 & "'!" & DropDownsSourceRange3Address 'Fundamentals for estimation
    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=DropDownsRangeName3, RefersTo:="='" & DropDownsSheetName & "'!" & DropDownsRange3Address 'where to place the DropDown based on above source

    SetDropDownList
End Sub

Sub DeleteNamedRanges()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Dim i As Long
    For i = ThisWorkbook.Names.Count To 1 Step -1
        Select Case ThisWorkbook.Names(i).Name
            Case DropDownsSourceRangeName, DropDownsRangeName, DropDownsSourceRangeName2, DropDownsRangeName2, DropDownsSourceRangeName3, DropDownsRangeName3
                ThisWorkbook.Names(i).Delete
            Case Else
                If InStr(ThisWorkbook.Names(i).Name, DropDownsSourceRangeName) Or _
                    InStr(ThisWorkbook.Names(i).Name, DropDownsRangeName) Then _
                    If InStr(ThisWorkbook.Names(i).Name, DropDownsSourceRangeName2) Or _
                    InStr(ThisWorkbook.Names(i).Name, DropDownsRangeName2) Then _
                    If InStr(ThisWorkbook.Names(i).Name, DropDownsSourceRangeName3) Or _
                    InStr(ThisWorkbook.Names(i).Name, DropDownsRangeName3) Then _
                        ThisWorkbook.Names(i).Delete
        End Select
    Next i
    
    Exit Sub
    
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "An error occurred " & Err.Description
End Sub

Sub SetDropDownList() 'No need of any iteration. Validation can be add from all the range, at once!
   Dim rngDropDown As Range, arrDrD(), arrSource(), arrAngle(), i As Long
   
   arrDrD = Array(DropDownsRangeName, DropDownsRangeName2, DropDownsRangeName3)
   arrSource = Array(DropDownsSourceRangeName, DropDownsSourceRangeName2, DropDownsSourceRangeName3)
   arrAngle = Array("Angle", "Angle1", "Angle2")
   
   For i = 0 To UBound(arrDrD)
      Set rngDropDown = Sheets(DropDownsSheetName).Range(arrDrD(i))
      
      With rngDropDown.Validation
          .Delete 'clear existd Validation rules, if any
          .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                        Operator:=xlBetween, _
                        Formula1:=getFormula1(CStr(arrSource(i)))
          .IgnoreBlank = True
          .InCellDropdown = True
          .InputTitle = vbNullString '"Select a value"
          .ErrorTitle = "Invalid value"
          .InputMessage = arrAngle(i)
          .ErrorMessage = "Select a valid value in the list."
          .ShowInput = True
          .ShowError = True
       End With
    Next i
End Sub

Function getFormula1(drDownSourceName As String) As String
    Const strStrange As String = "|#$%^"
    Dim rng As Range, arr, arr1
    
    Set rng = Range(drDownSourceName) 'set the range where from to extract the list  (without blanck  cells)
    arr1 = rng.Value 'place the range in an array to finally drop its content back
    
    rng.Replace "", strStrange, xlWhole 'replace the empty cells with strStrange
    arr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(rng) 'place the range in a 1D array
    arr = Filter(arr, strStrange, False) 'replace the former empty cells (strStrange array elements)
    getFormula1 = Join(arr, ",")
    rng.Value = arr1 'place back the original range content
End Function
```

a. It validates **without iteration between each ranges cell**, not being necessary.

b. `getFormula1` takes a parameter and it also **do not use iteration**.

2. Please, copy the next code event in sheet "Fundfakt-kateg-vinkl" code module:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
  AddNamedRangeAndSetDropDown 'it recreates the validations according the the last changes in source sheets (when this sheet is activated)
End Sub

Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 'limit the event to trigger ONLY THE NECESSARY DROPDOWN RANGES:
 If Not Intersect(Target, Union(Me.Range(DropDownsRangeAddress), _
       Me.Range(DropDownsRange2Address), Me.Range(DropDownsRange3Address))) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Value = "" Then Exit Sub

    If Left(Target.Value, 1) = "*" And Right(Target.Value, 1) = "*" Then
        MsgBox "You can't select a heading: '" & Target.Value + "'" & vbCr & vbCr & vbTab & "Try again. ", vbCritical
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        'Target.Value = ""
         Application.Undo  'place back the value existing before change!
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

The code is not triggered by changing a cell **not intersecting with the three ranges which the above code processes**.

It also does need `BeforeCellChange` function. It searches inside the validation list, not in the range where it came from. It is enough to have the headers with "*" character as first and last character.

Please, send some feedback after testing it. I will send back the test working workbook, in a comment.

Comment: @Unicorn Please, download the working workbook from [here](https://easyupload.io/13i1cx) and send some feedback.

Comment: I just tested your Excel, and it works just like I wanted. Everything is outstanding! I really appreciate your patience with this, thank you very much! It's getting late here, will try some more tomorrow, but for now I couldn't find anything that doesn't work as I wanted.

Comment: One problem has arisen: In my original version , I had the SheetsOP as a module VBA code (same as DropDownsOP, also module). I saw that you have put the SheetsOP as a sheet VBA code. After I implemented your solution, it seemed to work just fine at first. But when closing and trying to re-open the workbook, I can' t any longer. I've troubleshooted several days, can't find any solution. I have a lot of other VBA codes in my workbook. Could it be that when your VBA code is put in the sheet VBA, it conflicts with other VBA codes in the workbook? Is it possible to have it as a module VBA instead?

Comment: @Unicorn It looks you do not understand too much VBA, even having a lot of code, no offence... 1. I answered your question as it has been formulated. 2. It does what you required in your question, but you did not mark the answer as accepted. 3. An event code is always associated to an object! Moving the event code in a standard module **it will do nothing**! 4. My above code shouldn't be in conflict with ANY CODE! If you have a problem, from this point of view, this should be only related to your implementation way. 5. Can you send me the file and clearly explain what do you mean by conflict?

Comment: Well, I moved the code from your sheet designation to the module section, and immediately the error messages stopped and everything works as intended. The only potential issue remaining is whether I can reopen the file after having saved it. I will try to exchange two module codes and worksheets. Please stay with me a while longer and I will mark your solution as accepted.

Comment: @Unicorn **"exchanging codes is not a way of working**! You must know/understand what you are doing and it looks that you don't... Did you design the existing code you are talking about? If you moved the code from sheet code module to a standard module, you only make **that respective code NOT WORKING, ANYMMORE**. And I don't care about the code acceptance! I have enough reputation to not care about it. I usually try helping people who looks that they know what they are doing... If you want me to offer help, you must start thinking in a logical way and explaining **what problem you have**.

Comment: @Unicorn Then, I offered myself to help you if I will be able to see the problematic workbook. Otherwise, nobody can help you. We here are not mind readers... I started thinking that you try playing with the code which you do not understand, not being designed by you. This is not a shame! But you will never solve it in the way you try. For instance, try selecting headers in the respective sheet where you moved the code. Will it let you selectin it? Certainly, yes. Probably, there are other events in the respective sheets. Do you understand what an event is?

Comment: An event is an action that causes the initiating of something (a code, a sub to be run). My workbook is too big and contains too many other VBA codes and sheets to be shared. I can not share my workbook publicly. Ok, if I put back your SheetsOP as a worksheet code, then I ask you how to combine it with the existing worksheet code. I have edited my original question and inserted the existing worksheet code (see above). The reason is that when I deleted this existing worksheet code, I began to get pop-up notifications and finally I could not save the file.

Comment: I received this error message earlier after I had pasted one of your VBAs as worksheet code and the other VBA as module code (just like in the sample Excel) into my master Excel: You may not use reference operators (such as unions, intersections, and ranges), array constants, or the LAMBDA function for Data Validation criteria. The Source currently evalutates to an error. Do you want to continue?

Comment: @Unicorn Saying only that, it does not mean too much if you do not tell me **on which code line the error is raised**?  1. Does the workbook I sent (the working one), raise such an error, or any error? Does it work as it should? 2. Is there **other code in the respective sheet code module**? 3. Can you share (somehow) the workbook in discussion, or a dummy one (in terms of used data)? 4. If my code works (tested by me) without raising any error, how else to understand what is happening in your (real) workbook? 5. I asked you and refuse to answer: Did **you** design the rest of the code?

Comment: On Thursday 7th September, I updated my original posting above. Two new sample files: https://easyupload.io/m/3zub3k In the .xlsm file, as soon as I begin adding drop-downs in the grey-shaded areas on worksheet Overview in columns G, H, I, AV, the file can't be re-opened again without an error  notification. This must be due to the current VBA codes in the sample Excel. The list items in all drop-downs on sheet Overview are not retrieved from any source sheet but have been entered in data validation lists on sheet Overview. In the .xlsx file, you can get the drop-downs on worksheet Overview.

Comment: Yesterday, I received this error notification in my master Excel when I tried to repair it: Excel was able to open the file by repairing or removing the unreadable content. Excel completed file level validation and repair. Some parts of this workbook may have been repaired or discarded. Removed feature: Data validation from /xl/worksheets/sheet10.xml part But in my master Excel, there is no data validation on that sheet! However, this repair notification is relevant now for the uploaded sample Excel as you can see from my previous comment.

Comment: @Unicorn I am afraid that we do not speak the same language and I am not referring to English, no offence... You share the workbook I done, working, without anything to be tested and a xlsx file without any code (such a file cannot keep any code) which is completely useless, too. Since, the file I sent works as it should, this means that  the problem is **strictly related to implementation inside your existing code/workbook**. So, without sending a workbook containing your code, plus a description related to what you want doing, NOBODY can help you.

Comment: There is a reason I added two files: As soon as I add a drop-down on worksheet Overview in the .xlsm file I can save but not re-open the file (which is the whole problem). So I added the drop-downs in a second file, the .xlsx file. This whole problem with not being able to add a drop-down on the worksheet Overview (or any added worksheet after you had completed the sample Excel) occurred after I had implemented your code. Do you mean that I should not be able to add a single drop-down on any added worksheet after I have implemented your code. I do not understand how much clear I can be?

Comment: The VBA that causes all this might be the worksheet VBA for the worksheet Fundfakt-kateg-vinkl:

If Not Intersect(Target, Union(Me.Range(DropDownsRangeAddress),

More specifically, the part "Union", because on one occasion in my master Excel got an error message about Union not being allowed. N.B.! When I refer to master Excel, the master Excel still confirms that there is something in your VBA that hinders me from adding more worksheets with drop-downs without being able to re-open the file after saving.

Comment: Very simple for you to test: Try and add a drop-down in a cell on sheet Overview.¨Then try to save and re-open the file. You will notice that it does not work.

Comment: @Unicorn I am afraid that trying to help you I am only wasting my time, sorry. Do you mean that this workbook becomes problematic **if I add one drop-down cell in Sheet Overview**? I manually added such a drop-down cell, save the workbook and the cell remained there after saving and reopening. You can download it from [here](https://easyupload.io/xgj6dj). The respective cell (G4) is highlighted to be easily observed. But you said something about "a lot of other VBA codes" and I cannot see anything else but my code. Is this aspect irrelevant?

Comment: I get this message when opening your file:
Microsoft Excel Security Notice
Microsoft has blocked macros from running because the source of this file is untrusted

Comment: For some reason, I have a .xlk file of my master Excel that is completely updated with the latest changes by me (including the addition of the two VBAs and all the drop-downs), and it works flawlessly (I can select list items in the drop-downs without any error message being generated). But when trying to save this .xlk file, I get no option in Excel to save as .xlk. How can I do that, save the Excel macro-enabled file as .xlk file?

https://www.lifewire.com/xlk-file-2622526#:~:text=or%20convert%20one.-,What%20Is%20an%20XLK%20File%3F,goes%20wrong%20with%20the%20document.

Comment: In this sample Excel that I uploaded earlier (uploaded here again), I just filled all grey-shaded areas with drop-downs, saved and tried to re-open. I still get the same error message as before (and as for my master Excel):

"We found a problem with some content in xxx.xlsm. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes."

Try to fill all grey-shaded areas with drop-downs by going to "Data/Data validation...", choose "List" beneath "Source" and enter the list items. Now you will not be able to re-open. https://easyupload.io/4t6yk8

Comment: I then tried to add only 1 drop-down in G4 and saved immediately and then re-opened without problems. So 1 drop-down works to re-open, but drop-downs in the whole grey-shaded cell range does not work to re-open. Here are the drop-downs if you want to copy and paste them: https://easyupload.io/qm4yhg    As I said, I am not able to add all these drop-downs in the .xlsm file because then the .xlsm file can not be  re-opened.

Comment: @Unicorn 1. It looks that you do not understand simple things (in Windows)...  You will always receive such an error ("Microsoft has blocked macros from running because the source of this file is untrusted"), if try opening **any** file downloaded from internet. **Before opening it you must right click on its icon, choose `Properties`,  tick the bottom right check box `UnBlock` and press OK**. Open it after you do that. 2. .xlk is a recovery file and it should be opened by Excel, then save it as what you want. You could share this file but **you did not do it**. 3. I cannot reproduce it.

Comment: @Unicorn 4. I do not understand what you hope sending me the last file. I cannot understand what it's happening in your environment. Do you have AnyDesk on your computer and allow a remote connection?

Comment: It seems like you can not understand simple things: I tell you that your test yesterday to add only 1 drop-down works fine for me also. But when you add drop-downs in all the grey-shaded areas, the file cannot be re-opened. This is the whole problem in a nutshell which I describe now in a few sentences. And you fail to understand it.

Comment: This is an evaluation of your VBA by an expert on VBA: It is not advisable to use worksheet event subs for updating things on other worksheets. Otherwise, a cascade of event subs will be triggered, each of these causing another event sub to run. Furthermore, the statement DropDownOP.SetDropDownList implies the sub of an Active-X object, which won't be recognized if its parent worksheet isn't active.

Comment: @Unicorn So, if I will send back (in less than two minutes) the workbook you sent with all the grayed ranges having drop-downs, will you admit that you do  not understand simple things? Why loosing time to only say something as: I can add a drop-down, but not more... Why all the useless staff you sent? I will send you the workbook as soon as I will add the drop-downs. In maximum two minutes.

Comment: @Unicorn That VBA expert does not know what VBA means. As you, it looks... Please, download from [here](https://easyupload.io/rn7a2t) your working workbook, containing drop-downs on the grayed ranges. And ask the pseudo expert what an event code means. My **only event code** does not change **anything in other sheets**. Even it can do it, of course, if he/you understand what you are doing... Please, put me in contact with the pseudo expert to see what he knows about VBA. May I know what expertize you have to qualify him as an expert? What notoriety does he have?

Comment: I tested it now. The first time I can save and re-open, the second time I get the same error notification as before. upon trying to re-open. Then I did a 2nd test: On the 4th saving I get the same error message as before upon trying to re-open.

The drop-downs are missing in the AV column. The IT expert in question has provided me with outstanding solutions for several years and I have the highest confidence in him.

Comment: @Unicorn History: 1. You asked for "adding two more source sheets with ranges for drop-downs. I provided an answer and sent a workbook able to do it. You said: "I just tested your Excel, and it works just like I wanted" - 2nd of September. 2. On 5th of September you starting saying about **your workbook** not working as you need. I told you that it is nothing related to my answer, it is strictly your implementation way. I asked to see that "a lot of code", or allow a connection to your computer to understand what you did wrong.

Comment: @Unicorn 3. You mentioned about the "expert" and **only now I can see the piece of code you pasted**: Where, **in my above answer, do you see `DropDownOP.SetDropDownList`**? This was **your contribution** to make a mess from my code. As I supposed **you have there the same event twice**.  4. I really do not know how to help you. We are talking different languages, so I wish you success! 5. Why don't you ask the expert to help with your problem?

Comment: Your code generates this error when I have deleted the code DropDownOP.SetDropDownList. I can provide you with a connection to my computer and you can see for yourself that your code generates this error in the sample Excel without the code DropDownOP.SetDropDownList as well as in my master Excel.

Comment: Among other certifications, the expert that commented on your code is a Microsoft Most Valuable Professional. Besides ridiculing his expertise, you are apt to criticize every aspect of my posting, including the work done by other SO members. I received the two VBAs referred to in this posting from Stack Overflow member Oscar Sun and am very content with the end result. His two VBAs did not cause any problems like yours did after having implemented them.

Comment: @Unicorn I can waste my time in many other ways. You are not able to understand. I was commenting about the "expert" in the context of what you said! **My event code does not change anything in other sheets**! The code example you wrote to prove what the "expert" said `DropDownOP.SetDropDownList` is not part of my code. I blamed the 'expert' only based on what you said! I was not sure that you do not know what you are doing, but it has been confirmed one more time. So, I wish you luck!

Comment: @Unicorn I tested my code on three different computers, different Office installations and **it works as it should, without any error**! P.S. If you are available for a remote connection I am open to it, to see what's happening in your installation and I will tell you how to fix it. Otherwise, as  I said, I wish you success in solving the problem!

Comment: what day and time is possible for you to have a remote connection? The error message pops up after I've selected a list object in a drop-down on sheet Fundfakt-kateg-vinkl, saved and try to re-open.

Comment: @Unicorn After so many days and your way of reacting I feel the need to state that I lost part of my enthusiasm in helping you... But if you reply in some minutes, I will be able to connect in the next minutes. I have some (limited) time and I can do it. But I will not wait for days near the computer... If you are available, you can send the AnyDesk ID on my personal mail (from mai profile). Before announcing me, please open a Notepad window to communicate in it.

Comment: I just installed AnyDesk on my computer and will send the AnyDesk ID shortly. The sample Excel is opened and beside it an empty Notepad. You can try to select list items in the drop-downs on both tabs Overview and Fundfakt-kateg-vinkl and then save in folder "1" (opened) and try to re-open the workbook. That's when the error message pops up.

Comment: @Unicorn No need to install it! Only download the file and open it. You will see its unique ID...

Comment: I see an address, is that what you mean? Ten digits. I already installed the software.

Comment: @Unicorn Yes, it can be of 9 or 10 digits.

Comment: @Unicorn Please, confirm its sending. My mail is configured to send any unknown sender in more Spam folders... I found the mail. Please accept connection.

Comment: @Unicorn I cannot see your status, to open the notepad file, to see Excel workbooks, VBE etc...