# Printing in Xps format Excel

Tags: excel, vba, printing

Good morning everyone.
I made an invoice in a excel sheet and need to print to a xps format, but I need an automatic printing... I mean, the invoice has a number and the directory to save the printing is always the same. Is there a way to avoid filedialog comes out to ask for the name and place, and set it up automatically, taking by the name the invoice number and let's say documents the default directory?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Where from "the invoice number" should be taken?

Comment: Do you really need help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the  next code. Take care to change the range where from the invoice number must be taken:

```
Sub SaveAsXPS()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, strPath As String, strName As String
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  If Dir(Environ("userProfile") & "\OneDrive", vbDirectory) <> "" Then
    strPath = Environ("UserProfile") & "\Onedrive\documents"
  Else
    strPath = Environ("UserProfile") & "\documents"
  End If
  strName = sh.Range("B3").value 'please use here the reall cell where the invoice number exists
 
    sh.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypeXPS, fileName:= _
        strPath & "\" & strName & ".xps", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: @arkero24 Didn't you find some time to test the above code? If tested, didn't it do what you need?

Comment: thank you very much. i will try it and let you to know the outcome

Comment: @arkero24 OK. But testing of such a code (**as it is**) should take no more than 2 minutes. You should try implementing in your (maybe larger) code, **only after seeing it working as it is**. It **answers your question as it has been formulated**! Its implementation is another issue.

Comment: Thanks @FaneDuru, it works very fine!! Thank you again

Comment: @arkero24 Glad I could help! But we here, when somebody answer our question in a convenient way, vote up the answer if enough reputation and tick the code left side check box, to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the suggested solution works...

Comment: Please, may I ask you,  how did you aquired that patience!

Comment: @Soma I am patient with people who may not know the community rules and prove that they know what they want. If not, I am not so patient, as you should know, I think... :) As exemplification, please look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76996971/in-my-excel-vba-how-can-i-add-more-defined-variables-for-adding-two-more-source/77028095?noredirect=1#comment135871154_77028095). I am not so proud of my behavior, but when what I write is in resonance with what I feel I do not delete the comments which may be not so appropriate for wise people...